# Using Rest Api In Java

Tags: rest, tomcat

I am using tomcat to deploy my war file and i have some rest api calls inside my war which actually starts a http server at a different port. When i pressed back button on my browser after my api call, i get this error. How can I resolve it?

> WARNING: Unable to parse the HTTP request java.io.IOException: Unable
>   to parse the request method. End of stream reached too early.     at
>   com.noelios.restlet.http.HttpServerCall.readRequestHead(HttpServerCall.java:347)
>     at
>   com.noelios.restlet.http.StreamServerCall.(StreamServerCall.java:88)
>     at
>   com.noelios.restlet.http.StreamServerHelper$ConnectionHandler.run(StreamServerHelper.java:86)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) Apr 30, 2012 10:13:22 AM
>   com.noelios.restlet.http.HttpServerCall parseHost INFO: Couldn't find
>   the mandatory "Host" HTTP header. Apr 30, 2012 10:13:22 AM
>   com.noelios.restlet.LogFilter afterHandle INFO:
>   2012-04-30    10:13:22    127.0.0.1   -   -   8182    -   -   -   404 330 -   0   http://null -   -
>   Apr 30, 2012 10:13:22 AM com.noelios.restlet.http.HttpServerConverter
>   commit SEVERE: An exception occured writing the response entity
>   java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the
>   software in your host machine     at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)     at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:33)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:104)  at
>   sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:75)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:334)    at
>   java.nio.channels.Channels.write(Channels.java:60)    at
>   java.nio.channels.Channels.access$000(Channels.java:47)   at
>   java.nio.channels.Channels$1.write(Channels.java:134)     at
>   java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
>     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
>     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:278)   at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:122)    at
>   java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:212)     at
>   org.restlet.resource.StringRepresentation.write(StringRepresentation.java:211)
>     at
>   com.noelios.restlet.http.HttpServerCall.writeResponseBody(HttpServerCall.java:492)
>     at
>   com.noelios.restlet.http.HttpServerCall.sendResponse(HttpServerCall.java:428)
>     at
>   com.noelios.restlet.http.HttpServerConverter.commit(HttpServerConverter.java:392)
>     at
>   com.noelios.restlet.http.HttpServerHelper.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:148)
>     at
>   com.noelios.restlet.http.StreamServerHelper$ConnectionHandler.run(StreamServerHelper.java:86)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) Apr 30, 2012 10:13:22 AM
>   com.noelios.restlet.http.HttpServerConverter commit WARNING: Unable to
>   send error response java.io.IOException: An established connection was
>   aborted by the software in your host machine  at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)     at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:33)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:104)  at
>   sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:75)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:334)    at
>   java.nio.channels.Channels.write(Channels.java:60)    at
>   java.nio.channels.Channels.access$000(Channels.java:47)   at
>   java.nio.channels.Channels$1.write(Channels.java:134)     at
>   java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
>     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
>     at
>   com.noelios.restlet.http.HttpServerCall.writeResponseHead(HttpServerCall.java:553)
>     at
>   com.noelios.restlet.http.StreamServerCall.writeResponseHead(StreamServerCall.java:201)
>     at
>   com.noelios.restlet.http.HttpServerCall.sendResponse(HttpServerCall.java:415)
>     at
>   com.noelios.restlet.http.HttpServerConverter.commit(HttpServerConverter.java:410)
>     at
>   com.noelios.restlet.http.HttpServerHelper.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:148)
>     at
>   com.noelios.restlet.http.StreamServerHelper$ConnectionHandler.run(StreamServerHelper.java:86)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Comment: Did you write the `com.noelios.restlet.http.HttpServerCall` class?  That's where the exception is being raised, so it's a good place to start looking.

Comment: I am using the api com.noelios.restlet, inside my application i just the link to my router to the resource class.